# How to use telegram api registerDevice for ESP8266?

Tags: communication, esp8266

I can't find any example for this method. I don't want to check the messages via "getMessages" method but want that telegram sends a TCP message to ESP8266, like my mobile or browser receive messages.

Here is the method description: https://core.telegram.org/method/account.registerDevice

I already tried a simple HTTP request like this: https://api.telegram.org/botIDgibberish/registerDevice?param&param

Is that possible?

Comment: Can you add some links to the relevant documentation?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the normal API with http GET like you suggest. You would have to use MTProto protocol that is propietary for Telegram or Bots.

With bots you can generate an own url to your local server, where you give yourself a deep link for the desired action, looking quite similar to that you provided.

There are more details and links under:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228368/how-to-interact-with-telegram-api

Links for use of telegram api in github, if you don't like bots (links mentioned under the same post):

https://github.com/zhukov/webogram

https://github.com/enricostara/telegram.link